# jquery not accessible after normal ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, partial-views

```
<ul id="months">
                <?php foreach ($months as $key => $value) { ?>
                    <?php if ($key != 0 && array_key_exists($key, $monthArray) && date("m") > $key) { ?>
                        <li id="<?= $key ?>"><a href="#" rel="nofollow"><?= $value ?></a></li>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

below is the jquery code

```
        $("#year").change(function(){
//        alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'ay/templates/frontend/_previous_months.tpl.php',
            data: 'year=' + $(this).val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#months").html(data);`
            }
        });
    });
```

**Problem :** when i first time request partial i get proper result, but after when i get months partial i can t access jquery from it,

below is the jquery function which i need to access after when i get my parial(**before making above ajax call, i can access below jquery function when i click on li item**)

```
$("#months li").click(function(){
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ay/templates/frontend/_previous_charities.tpl.php',
        data: 'month=' + $(this).attr("id") + '&year=' + $('#year').val(),
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'false'){
                $("#charity_result").html("No previous charity in selected Month");
            }else{
                $('#charity_result').fadeOut('slow');
                //                $('#ajax-result').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#charity_result').fadeIn('slow');
                $("#charity_result").html(data);

            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `click` event is not added to your `#months li`.
Try using the live method: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Instead of:

`$("#months li").click(function() {`

use this:

`$("#months li").live('click', function() {`

Comment: thanks man, it just worked, accepting your answer, once again thanks

Comment: i clicked on it, but a message appaeard saying u can accept in 15 minutes,

sorry mate ;-)

Comment: thanks, i hope to come soon with more questions, as i am working on a project which involves alot of jquery, i am glad that you took interest in my issue, bless you

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. 
(But it works fine ^^ althought)

Comment: you right, jquery documentation says it, but i am using older version of library which is supporting `.live` and not `.on`

Comment: Haha no prob, We're in the same way ^^